# Hyper-V encountered an error while configuring network on New Virtual Machine, because the object was not found

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

While creating new VM I am trying to attach existing VHDX created earlier.

But this fails with following error.

Hyper-V encountered an error while configuring network on New Virtual Machine, because the object was not found.

I am already runnig Hyper-V as administrator & have verfied that VHD do exist. What could be the issue?

Comment: I tried to post screenshot of the error but unable to do so, now. Will post it soon once I get 10 reputation here.

Comment: In my case - not enough free space on HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this problem myself while adding certain VHKD files to new and existing Hyper-V virtual machines, I never really dug around that much as I have experience loads of problems adding virtual hard disks to Hyper-V unless they were VHD format.

This is more of a work around than a solution, but it may help you; I downloaded this tool

http://download.softwaretipspalace.com/Windows/System-Utilities/Other/V2V-convertertion-tool_7728.html

Which is completely free! It allows you to take a VHKD and convert it to a VHD! It doesnt take that long either, I would imagine it would work after doing this.

Comment: Hi Thaks for your answer, you mean to say the issue exists for VHDX and should be reslved once this is converted to VHD.

Comment: I am not saying there is an 'official' issue with VHDX, but I have experienced issue's myself and have since came up with this work around.